# How to return the largest number returning from a function in which the Object.values(obj) is used in it to return an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

In this example I am trying to get the largest number of a returning array that's been returned from using the `Object.values(obj)`,`Array.reduce()` and `Array.length`  on the object `scoreObj` .
I reached to the point where I got the array with the new numbers (the average numbers of each array in the object) from which I want to get the largest number.

As you see in the code snippet the `getObjecVals()` returns the average number of each array in the object `scoreObj` .At this point I got stuck at returning the largest number from the new array.

I hope the code snippet makes more sense than my explanation. I am a bit confused as well because when I use the `typeof` operator on `getObjecVals()` it executes `undefined` albeit the new array of numbers.
So my issues are:-

1. Why the typeof `getObjecVals()` returns `undefined` and at the same time it logs with an array of numbers?
2. How can I get the largest number out of the three numbers returning from `getObjecVals()`?

   ```js
   let scoresObj = {
     johnsScore: [89, 120, 103],
     mikesScores: [116, 94, 123]
   };
   const marys = scoresObj.marysScore = [97, 134, 105];

   const getAverage = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0) / arr.length;

   const getObjecVals = () => {
     for (let value of Object.values(scoresObj)) {
       console.log(getAverage(value));
     }
   }
   getObjecVals(); // returns 104 111 112
   ```

*PS: I am always open to new ways of getting the desired result, but I'd rather find a way to get my own code to do it.*

Comment: please add the wanted result. btw, a function needs a returns statement, if not an arrow function without a block statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `getObjecVals()` returns `undefined` because you didn't return any values for this funciton.
2. If you just want to get the max. average number, I would just store all of the data as an array and use some array function to get the result.

```js
const scoresObj = {
  johnsScore: [89, 120, 103],
  mikesScores: [116, 94, 123],
};

scoresObj.marysScore = [97, 134, 105];

console.log(scoresObj);

const getObjecVals = scoresObj => {
  let maxObj = {
    objName: null,
    maxAverageValue: -1,
  };
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(scoresObj)) {
    const average = value.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / value.length;
    if (average > maxObj.maxAverageValue) {
      maxObj.objName = key;
      maxObj.maxAverageValue = average;
    }
  }
  return maxObj;
};

console.log(getObjecVals(scoresObj));
```

Comment: Fantastic! but what if we want to keep the object of arrays as it is as it's important to keep the keys?

Comment: @Mozaick, I updated the answer. Please see if the output is what you want.

Comment: That's the one. Thank you.